# Hide functions/vuex module from clientside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a vuex module that i want to be used/imported only when the user call its, but when i import it in the vuex.modules it imports globally so the functions can be viewed from devtools.

I read functions/modules could be hidden with SSR either using Nuxt or another library.
Is this possible? is there a way to hide functions/modules from the client-side either using vuex or not?
Or at least hide the functions temporary while they are not called from the source?.

Comment: What is the problem that you try to solve? All the code that you use on client side is accessible to anyone who can access this page.

Comment: You could obfuscate the code, even tho I'm not sure this is anyhow useful in any circumstances.

Comment: Considering that all the code used in clientside is accessible in the source... is there at least a way to send X module code to the clientside only when the user call its? or for example only when user is logged in?. I'd try to send the module obfuscated at least.

Comment: There is code splitting actually yeah (per page) or some lazy loading of a script. Otherwise, you can always host the code on server and fetch it from there. What is so sensitive there?

Comment: I understand, i think i will try using SSR... do you know any example for fetching scripts/modules from server-side to clientside? Thanks.

Comment: Reach and endpoint, get the actual script and inject it.

Comment: Do you have any example code or guide?...

Comment: I don't know what is your backend. Google it with your backend. Create an endpoint, with a route and expose some script there. Then you could axios get that and use it in your app.